# Getting NaN after adding the same number twice

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, state

I'm having an issue with my code , when I try to add the same number (amount) to my input - I'm getting NaN.
It only happens when I add two identical numbers (66 and then 66 for example) - but it does work properly when I add a different number.

**App.js :**

```
import Outcome from "./components/Outcome";
import Income from "./components/Income";

const App = () => {
  const [sum, setSum] = useState(0);

  const onChangeHandlerOutcome = (value) => {
    setSum((prevState) => prevState - value);
    console.log(value);
  };

  const onChangeHandlerIncome = (value) => {
    setSum((prevState) => prevState + value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Outcome onChangeHandlerOutcome={onChangeHandlerOutcome} />
      <Income onChangeHandlerIncome={onChangeHandlerIncome} />
      You have {sum}$!
    </div>
  );
};

export default App
```

**Income.js :**

```
const Income = (props) => {
  const [input, setInput] = useState(0);

  const setInputHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setInput(e.target.value);
    props.onChangeHandlerIncome(input);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={setInputHandler}>
        <label>
          Income
          <input
            type="text"
            name="name"
            onChange={(e) => setInput(parseInt(e.target.value))}
          ></input>
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"></input>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Income;
```

I have tried using prevState, and simply adding value to the sum and had the same result.

Also console.logged the value : adding two similar numbers logged me this :

**123 (which is the number i typed in)

App.js:10 undefined**

I appreciate any kind of help!

Comment: You are resetting input state (setInput) again in setInputHandler while it is already being set in onChange handler of input element.
In setInputHandler, you are setting it as string while in input Onchange it is being set as a number.
Also change input type text to number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before submit. You have re-set state for input value again, also it will be set 'undefined' (variable `e.target` here is `<form>`, which does not have value). After that, App will update sum is `numer + undefined === NaN`. It is no need re-set state input because of input value will always be updated on Input OnChange. Just:

```
const setInputHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    //setInput(e.target.value);
    props.onChangeHandlerIncome(input);
};
```

Comment: thank you kind sir, for some reason i have not noticed that.

Answer (score 1):

`type="text"` could be replaced with `type="number"`
Also, you need some parser with guard to avoid NaN. For example:

```
const parseAmount = (str) => str ? parseInt(str, 10) : 0;
```

Then

```
onChange={(e) => setInput(parseAmount(e.target.value))}
```

and

```
const setInputHandler = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const amount = parseAmount(e.target.value);
  setInput(amount);
  props.onChangeHandlerIncome(amount);
};
```